# PHP: how do I copy a temp file upload to multiple places?

Tags: php, file-upload

how can I copy two times the same file? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
                copy($file['tmp_name'], $folder."1.jpg");
            copy($file['tmp_name'], $folder."2.jpg");
            copy($file['tmp_name'], $folder."3.jpg");
```

And how many time does temp files has before it's destroyed by the server?

I try using move_uploaded_file also, but I can't make it work. I want to generate 2 thumbs from an uploaded file.

Some help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`move_uploaded_file`](http://fr.php.net/move_uploaded_file) will move the file, and not copy it -- which means it'll work only once.

If you are using [`copy`](https://www.php.net/copy), there shouldn't be any limit at all on the number of times you can copy : the temporay file created by the upload will only be destroyed at the end of the execution of your script *(unless you move/delete it before, of course)*

Still, maybe a solution would be to use `move_uploaded_file` first, and, then, `copy` ?

A bit like that, I suppose :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $folder . '1.jpg')) {
    copy($folder . '1.jpg', $folder . '2.jpg');
    copy($folder . '1.jpg', $folder . '3.jpg');
}
```

This would allow you to get the checks provided by `move_uploaded_file`...

If this doesn't work, then, make sure that :

- `$folder` contains what you want -- including the final `/`
- That `$file['tmp_name']` also contains what you want *(I'm guessing this is some kind of copy of `$_FILES` -- make sure the copy of `$_FILES` to `$file` is done properly)*

Answer (score 4):

Why doesn't `move_uploaded_file()` work? Are you trying to use it twice? You can't do that, it moves it, so the second time will fail.

I would just use `move_uploaded_file()` once, and then make the second copy from the location you just moved it to:

```
move_uploaded_file($uploaded, $destination);
copy($destination, $destination2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reply to your question directly but how about this workaround ?

```
copy($file['tmp_name'], $folder."1.jpg");
copy($folder."1.jpg"  , $folder."2.jpg");
copy($folder."1.jpg"  , $folder."3.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks man, you give me the light.

I made something like this:

```
    $objUpload = new Upload();
    $filename = $objUpload->uploadFile($newFile,$folder); 
// returns a string    
    $objUpload->makeThumb($filename,$folder,"thumbs",139); 
// makes a 139px thumbnail from the original file uploaded on the first step
    $objUpload->makeThumb($filename,$folder,"mini",75); 
// makes another thumb from the same file
```

Using move_ulploaded_file and copy we can make only one thumb. :)