# upload file in php

Tags: php

how i can upload single file to a
**multiple location** or folder

i use move_uploaded_file() two times but it work only one time

Comment: Same question and nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427936/php-copy-problem-with-uploaded-file

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
copy($source_file, $destination_file);
```

Where `$source_file` is the file you have just uploaded's path and `$destination_file` is where you want the copy to reside.

Answer (score 4):

use `copy`

see this link
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 3):

You are working on a normal file system, so if you have an path to your file, just use [copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).