# How to get file temporary path in php while file upload

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, uploadify

I am using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) jQuery plugin for file upload.Here there is no browse button used.
it will upload the file using ajax on click event.So There is no file temp path is displaying.So i want to make it display.

So, I try to get file temp path using **$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']**. But it just return something like this **/tmp/phpclqHXj**.But i want display actual temp path like **C:\Users\Diamantino\Desktop\file.jpg**.Can i get this using php. any option in uploadify
plugin, anyway to get jquery or js.Any help would be appreciated.

My Browse button.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Related, though not really a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427936/php-copy-problem-with-uploaded-file

Comment: You need to display path on page? Or you need it in PHP script?

Comment: @Timur: I want it display in my page. not php.if possible in php i return it from ajax page.if possible in jquery i will use it directly on my page

Comment: @gowri, Uploadify displays the name of selected files. You need full path instead? It is may be under some security restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the full path to the file from your user's computer. You can get the file name (in your example that would be `"file.jpg"`) using `$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']`. Security issues would arise if you could get information about your user's local folder structure when they upload a file, so web browsers are very unlikely to send that data. If there is some browser that does send it, it won't appear in the `$_FILES` superglobal, nor will there be any other easy way to access is in php.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you're looking for the filename found under:

```
$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']
```

Instead of **C:\Users\Diamantino\Desktop\file.jpg**, this will return the filename: **file.jpg**

However, with the use of simple Javascript, you may be able to accomplish getting the entire file path. With some logic on your end, you may be able to get the file path only when the file is uploaded. Here is an [example](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=202162.0), and some [clarity on implementation](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=202162.0).

Comment: :i'm not looking for file name.looking for only full temp path